# JSON output indenting on Actionscript 3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, air

I'm using the native JSON functionality of Adobe AIR 3. My objects are being successfully converted to JSON strings with the native "JSON.stringify()" function but all data is being written on one line with no spaces. Is there a way to make this output human-readable with correct tabs and spaces?

Comment: Old question but all the answers are just RTFM. Working example: `JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);` would indent 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html
stringify have optional parameter space. Did you try it?

Comment: Actually I peeked into that page before and thought it was just for adding spaces between fields. I'll read it again.

Comment: I was hoping for an easier solution but I guess there are none. I'll just set this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [this](http://maccherone.com/larry/projects/older/a-pretty-json-encoder-for-actionscript-3-as3/) to be a good library to get "pretty" JSON. It's based on the as3corelib JSON encoder. I don't think it has been updated for a while, but it does the trick

http://maccherone.com/larry/projects/older/a-pretty-json-encoder-for-actionscript-3-as3/

Comment: More information about it here: http://maccherone.com/larry/2009/05/28/actionscript-3-as3-json-encoder-with-pretty-output-by-adding-linefeeds-and-spaces/

Comment: thanks but I'd like to use the AS3's native JSON parser if possible.